# the "org-preview-latex-fragment" command in emacs org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

5here is a command named `org-preview-latex-fragment` in `org-mode`. its default binding key is `C-c C-x C-l`. In the org manual, it says this command could preview a latex fragment inline. but after using it, nothing is produced but blank frames (I can't upload images, sorry).

What happened? I'm using emacs23.1 on Ubuntu10.10, the org-mode version is 6.21b, and I've installed dvipng version 1.13-1.

I tried trace the code, but got lost. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you try the `org mdoe` mailing list?

Comment: Yes, please email the Org mode mailing list.  Also consider updating, as 6.21b is just prehistoric.

Comment: In ubuntu, you could install the `org-mode` package to upgrade org-mode to 7.8.11 which should be sufficient. See https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/org-mode

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to debug is to try to compile the temporary file created to create the fragment. It is usually located in `/tmp` and contains `orgtex` in the filename. You can find the exact name in Emacs's `*Messages*` buffer.

Answer (score 1):

I resolve the problem by changing the program to convert latex fragment from `dvipng` to `imagemagik`. 
I guess something is missing on my computer.

```
\M-x customize-variable RET org-latex-create-formula-image-program \RET
```

**Update:**

you can event increase the preview size by doing

```
\M-x customize-variable RET Org Format Latex Options RET
```

**Update 2**

I had some problem with `imagemagick` Have a look at the and switch back to dvipng after following the instruction in the [doc](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-latex-preview.html). So both work correclty.